# Regex in mysql to match digits with leading 0

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to match in sql using the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE vendor_id REGEXP '^0\d+'
```

However, it returns no results. Doing `vendor_id REGEX '^0'` works though. How do I search for 0 followed by other digits?

Comment: What is the datatype of `vendor_id`??

Comment: Are you asking how to _search_, or how to _extract_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL regex uses [**POSIX Extended Regular Expression (ERE)**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#ere) that doesn't know about PCRE regex property classes such as `\d`, `\w` etc. You can use `[0-9]` or POSIX class `[[:digit:]]` as:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE vendor_id REGEXP '^0[0-9]+'
```

OR else:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE vendor_id REGEXP '^0[[:digit:]]+'
```